# magento 2.1.6 email template after save 404 not found

Tags: adminhtml, email-templates, magento2.1.6

I am trying to create new email template with loading existing one By navigating

**Marketing => Email Template => Add New Templates and load "new invoice" email**

and without changes anything.After save i got **404 error: Page not found.**

Can any one help me on this problem ?.Any references or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Any solutions please?